# Junk Characters being added to string when reading HTTP request parameters

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, forms

I have an html form :

```
<p> Select beer characteristics </p>
<p> 
  Color: 
  <select name="color" size="1">
    <option value="light"> light </option>
    <option value="amber"> amber </option>
    <option value="brown"> brown </option>
    <option value="dark"> dark </option>
  </select>
  <br><br> 
</p>
<input type = "submit" value="submit">
```

- for the input parameter name = "color", there are four options: light, amber, brown, dark
- based on which value is chosen, a result page is shown
- however, when I select an option, there are some junk characters being added in front and at the end of the string for the option value
- on debugging, this is the value read (on selecting "amber") when I read using request.getParameter("color") look like:
  â€amberâ€
- this is causing a problem in the back end where i want to do a string match with the input parameter

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong kind of quote characters in your HTML code.

What you probably have is something like this:

```
<option value=“light“>
```

Unless you use the correct double quotes (") or single quote (') to enclose an attribute, the browser will interpret the value as `“light“` and not `light`, and that's what it sends to the server.

*(Note that this wouldn't be valid in XHTML, where only quoted attributes are allowed, but in plain HTML specifying attributes in a `<foo bar=value>` format works.)*

The strange output can be explained by the fact that your browser and your server use different encodings: one uses ISO-8859-1 and the other UTF-8. The UTF-8 sequence for the left double quotation mark character is `0xe2 0x80 0x9c`, which when read with ISO-8859-1, gives exactly the two characters you mention. (The third one falls in an unused block and is dropped silently.)

This is a separate problem that needs to be remedied too, see the other answers for tips to deal with it.

Comment: What? Wrong quotes where? Oh, do you mean in the HTML source? They're showing up as normal quotes for me.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, although the HTML in the question contains the correct character, I recognise the output as a mis-coded left- or right double quote (I forgot which)

Comment: I tend towards this explanation rather than a bogus encoding.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm fairly confident that this is the case, particularly after figuring out that if the other encoding isn't Windows-1250 but ISO-8859-1, all the characters in the output match up.

Answer (score 2):

This is result of wrong encoding in browser, which is most probably not set on response. You can try to use:

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

I am quite sure that this is related to character encoding or URL encoding mismatches.

First of all, make sure to **specify a charset**

```
<form action="..." method="..." accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <select ...> ... </select>
</form>
```

If the client sends all your stuff correctly with a good encoding (UTF-8), you have to configure your server side to read the data as well.

I don't know what you're using, but one method is:

```
URLDecoder.decode(formParams, "UTF-8");
```

To be sure, you can add an encoding to your HTML file as well:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    ...
</head>
```

Edit: make sure to **send and receive** all the stuff correctly as well.

Sending HTML file from Server:

1) Make sure to set this:
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

If you're sending a file, make sure to save your file using the UTF-8 encoding.
If your HTML is a generated String, use:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(httpOutputStream, "UTF-8"));
writer.print(string);
...
```

The URL from the request is received in US-ASCII encoding:

```
String urlEncodedString = new String(receivedBytes, "UTF-8");
String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(urlEncodedString, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while converting xhtml to PDF using wkhtmltopdf
tool.

Adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` in my HTML template resolved the issue.